# Vector of 1s and sum of elements

Tags: algorithms

I stumbled on the following computing issue and would like some help to solve it. Given a vector of size n and filled with 1's, give all the elements obtained by the sum of them. Ignore combinatorial options like [m, n] and [n, m]

Example: n = 5, v = [1,1,1,1,1]: The possibilities are below:

```
[2, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 1], [3, 2]
[4, 1]
[5]
```

Take note: the elements are in front of one another only when 1s are summed together. Otherwise, they are placed on the next row.

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm that outputs all the possibilities row by row as illustrated?

Comment: It may or may not be as illustrated as denoted in the post. The only requirement is that the total number of partitions fulfills the cardinality of the table in the URL: http://oeis.org/wiki/Partition_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task can be done conveniently by a recursive algorithm.

Fix the total sum `n`. A partition of `n` can be viewed as a decreasing sequence of positive integers that sum up to `n`. If the initial segment of decreasing sequence has been selected, the remaining sequence is naturally a partition of `s` into numbers that are at most the least of the selected numbers, where `s` is `n` subtracted by the sum of the selected numbers.
Thus we can construct partitions recursively.

---

Here is an implementation in Python.

The function `partitions_recursive` puts partitions of number `s` with decreasing parts, each part at most `m`, in the array `buffer` starting at index `start`.

```python
def partitions(n):
    all_partitions = []
    buffer = [0] * n

    def partitions_recursive(start, s, m):
        """sum(buffer[index:]) will be s. Each entry will be at most m"""
        if s == 0:
            all_partitions.append(buffer[:start].copy())

        for part in range(1, min(s, m) + 1):
            buffer[start] = part
            partitions_recursive(start + 1, s - part, min(m, part))

    partitions_recursive(0, n, n)
    return all_partitions


print(partitions(5))
# [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [3, 1, 1], [3, 2], [4, 1], [5]]
```

Comment: Click the green "Run" button [here](https://replit.com/@Apass_Jack/cs150270partitions#main.py) to see more output.

Comment: Fascinating. I got stuck on the recursion step. :(. If you are a Naruto's fan, it is like Itachi's jutsu "Izanami".